# "Raw" string in Haskell for Regular Expression

Tags: regex, haskell

I appear to be having trouble creating a regular expression in Haskell, what I'm trying to do is convert this string (which matches a URL in a piece of text)

```
\b(((\S+)?)(@|mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://)\S+)\b
```

Into a regular expression, the trouble is I keep getting this error in ghci

```
Prelude Text.RegExp> let a = fromString "\b(((\S+)?)(@|mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://)\S+)\b"

<interactive>:1:27:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character 'S'
```

I'm guessing it's failing because Haskell doesn't understand `\S` as an escape code. Are there any ways to get around this?

In Scala you can surround a string with 3 double quotes, I was wondering if you could achieve something similar in Haskell?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: according the answers found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792267/haskell-do-literal-backslashes-always-have-to-be-escaped-in-a-string haskell does not have any syntax for raw strings so you have to escape every backslash like @augustss said.

Comment: ..and I believe you have to be using pcre-light or regex-pcre to get an implementation that knows about \S.  Besides the perl-like engines there are posix-like engines such as regex-tdfa (that does not recognize \s).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every backslash in your string has to be written as a double backslash inside the double quotes.  So

```
"\\b(((\\S+)?)(@|mailto\\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\\://)\\S+)\\b"
```

A more general remark: you'd be better off writing a proper parser rather than using regular expressions.  Regular expressions rarely do exactly the right thing.

Comment: ... hmm - but: regular expressions should be much faster. Writing a LR or LL-Parser for a Type-3-language shouldnt be an efficient solution.

Comment: @phynfo, however, a parser will allow you to use patterns composably and to easily extract information from the parse.  Speed isn't everything.

Comment: @phyinfo If speed is of utmost importance I'd use a simple regular expression that recognizes a superset of the valid URLs and then use a real parser to verify those.

Comment: I couldn't get the above example to work, I'm a bit amateurish when it comes to regular expressions but the above expression works fine in Scala but nothing matches in Haskell. augustss comment has inspired me to look for a different approach, all I want to do is extract URLs from some text. My current (naive) solution is to use `words text` and return any strings that start with http://

Comment: +1 for correct answer, yet I'm tempted to take it away for "Regular expressions rarely do exactly the right thing."  Regexes are just like any other programming language - they do exactly what they're told to do.  Don't blame the tool.

Comment: @rampion Yes, it was a bit sloppily formulated, I should have said "Complicated regular expressions rarely do exactly what you think they should."

Comment: @djhworld There are many versions of regexps, not all support \S.

Comment: I'm downvoting you because of the general note.

Comment: @Paul Regular expressions are overused, I think they should be discouraged.

Answer (score 6):

Haskell doesn't support raw strings out of the box, however, in GHC it's very easy to implement them using [quasiquotation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Quasiquotation):

```
r :: QuasiQuoter
r = QuasiQuoter {      
    quoteExp  = return . LitE . StringL
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
ghci> :set -XQuasiQuotes
ghci> let s = [r|\b(((\S+)?)(@|mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://)\S+)\b|]
ghci> s
"\\b(((\\S+)?)(@|mailto\\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\\://)\\S+)\\b"
```

I've released a slightly more expanded and documented version of this code as the [`raw-strings-qq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/raw-strings-qq) library on Hackage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of the Rex library:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rex

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/rex/0.4.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-PCRE-Rex.html

Which not only uses quasiquoting for nice regex entry (no double backslashes), it also uses perl-like regular expressions and not the default annoying POSIX regular expressions, and even allows you to use regular expressions as pattern matching your method parameters, which is genius.